# jQuery Mobile growing text area with AJAX data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am loading text to an input box via the `$("textarea").val(ajaxData);` however it will not autogrow, and my data is not fully displayed. Is there any method or anything that I can call to force an update?

Comment: Please post your CSS, javascript and HTML - most likely your problem is because of your CSS.

Comment: I have no custom css, this is for a normal textbox. the only difference is that input comes not from keyboard but from ajax data source. So there is must be a function to do this on jQM, I just don't know witch one it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's indeed an internal function that is responsible for resizing, called `resizeCheck()`. However, that function is a private implementation detail and is not exposed by the widget as a public method.

You can work around this, though: since `resizeCheck()` is called by the widget's `keyup` event handler, you can trigger that event yourself after setting the new value:

```
$("textarea").val(ajaxData).keyup();
```

This will resize the widget in the exact same way as if you had typed the new text "by hand".

Comment: Thank you again Frédéric, you have saved me hours of search. It work perfect! :) However once the field grows it will not go back... i found this behavior doing manual edits as well. is there a way to reset this field to normal? Could this be a bug?

Comment: @Adam, this is indeed a bug. [Bug #2719](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2719), to be specific.

Comment: Thanks once again for your feedback. I think i will merge the elastic plugin, it is a bummer since I wanted to use the CDN instead of a local jQuery.

Comment: Is there a parameter to force it to scroll instead of growing?

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't.

Comment: Frédéric do you know how-to do programmatically toggle navbars, the CSS oriented nature of jQM baffles me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821984/how-do-i-programmatic-toggle-navbar-tabs-in-jquery-mobile Thanks!

Comment: been banging my head, this is perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
var offset=15;
$("textarea").val(ajaxData);
$("textarea").height($("textarea").innerHeight() + offset)
```

You can try without any offset if it works in your case. You can also change the offset value if be needed

Comment: Hi thanks for this solution. However I was wondering if anyone knows what function is called internally by jQM to do this with regular input text. if you type it autogrows, but it will not with ajax data.

Comment: Hi Imdad would innerHeight give me the value of the text? Can I use this to make it elastic? Grow and Shrink?

Comment: innerHeight  will give you height of inner content. So, you can grow/shrink accordingly. To get value or the actual text use `$("textarea").val()`

Comment: sorry I meant value of the text height. I will test.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a height : 'auto' in your container element using CSS.

If you wrote a static height it will not autogrow.