# jQM checkboxes, how to change states?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

It looks like jQM uses CSS checkboxes. Is there any simple way to toggle states? Or do I need to always change the class via CSS?

Off

```
<label id="RememberMe" for="checkbox-1" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last ui-checkbox-off ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Memorize</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-off"></span>
    </span>
</label>
```

ON

```
<label id="RememberMe" for="checkbox-1" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Memorize</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-on"></span>
    </span>
</label>
```

Is there a simpler way than to change CSS class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to change the `checked` property of the underlying `<input>` element, then refresh the jQuery Mobile widget:

```
$("#checkbox-1").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: Well that was about perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Frédéric perhaps you know the proper way to also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699210/jquery-mobile-growing-text-area-with-ajax-data it would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#checkbox-1").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```