# How do I programmatic toggle navbar tabs in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I toggle the navbar's interface in jQuery Mobile so i can press a button in a div and display a different navbar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### jsFiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CrbbU/) of jQuery Mobile NAV Toggle

I have created a **jsFiddle Demo** via the link above that should address your question.

In particular, you can **set the NAV Bar** easily as well as **toggle it to and from** different bars.

I say different bars because the fiddle allows for as **many more NAV bars** as you require, and is very **easy** to adapt. To be sure, any NAV bar **[maxs-out](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)** at **5 buttons**.

**EDIT:** Per your message comments, it's easy to **navigate between pages** once more than 1 page is created. This different **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39wFb/)** shows how to **label the anchor tags** to switch pages on-the-fly. This **can be used** with the original jsFiddle Answer to provide a **complete** solution.

**RE-EDIT:** Per your most recent comments, this **new** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pG2ZA/) allows toggling of the buttons contents while on the same page.

Provided are simple **fiddle comments** to understand what's going on, but ask about anything unclear.

Comment: Hi @Efthimis let me illustrate what i need... I have two tabs on top, that represent two pages, in my code wend I press a next button I need to change the color of the tab, on tab two I have a button to go back that needs to toggle the first tab, here's an illustration  http://imgur.com/UYcBZ

Comment: @AdamSurfari, this is arttronics. In my demo you will see the `data-theme` attribute which specifies button color for individual anchor links. a=black, b=blue, e=yellow, [etc](http://codiqa.com/embed/editor). The anchor link themselves are **ready to use** and can each **can be set** to call the desired NAV State required. Does that help?

Comment: The issue is that I don't have two pages or two sets of navbar anchors. I have two divs so I only have a set of navbar links that I need to change with a onclick event.

Comment: **EDIT:** 3rd jsFiddle has been provided in RE-EDIT Section of my Answer that you can also access [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/pG2ZA/). Enjoy!

Comment: That is almost it but I can see that you identified the     $('#navbar-1 ul li a').each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-active');
    });  necessary proprity. Thanks! I think I can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks! They are a lot of classes that can be added or removed to achieve a visual button state, like button up or down. Also, you can force a button to be active in state but it's default scheme color is seen **until it's hovered over**. Note jQuery Mobile docs says do not use Document Ready but their own version [HERE](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html), except that breaks for PC dev work which might be the reason why. I used HTML tab of Firebug to view current state of buttons during interaction to see what jQuery does, and mimic that behavior.

Comment: I think the bounty is only attributed after it expires.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the updatelayout event. This event is triggered by components within the framework that dynamically show/hide content, and is meant as a generic mechanism to notify other components that they may need to update their size or position.
example from jQuery site:

```
$( '#foo' ).hide().trigger( 'updatelayout' );
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? What I want to do is have an external button that toggle two navbar "tabs". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?
http://jsfiddle.net/cHrSN/18/

Comment: Hi @Efthimis let me illustrate what i need... I have two tabs on top, that represent two pages, in my code wend I press a next button I need to change the color of the tab, on tab two I have a button to go back that needs to toggle the first tab, here's an illustration  http://imgur.com/UYcBZ

Answer (score 0):

Do your tabs have to be intergated in the JQM urlHistory or browser history?

If not, I changed a [collapsible-set](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html) into a tabviewer, so instead of having collapsibles **top-down**, I changed the widget to support data-type="horizontal" and then displayed the collapsibles **left to right** with the content section showing as a tab. I also added next-previous buttons, so you can go back and forth by either clicking on the tab buttons or on the prev-next buttons.

However, it all happens inside the page, so no browser back-button support.

If this goes in the right direction, I can put up a sample page and explanation.

Comment: No tabs don't need to be on url it's just a visual change to display if you are in input mode or graphic mode. I bascially need to programatcly change the active parameter of the tabs.