# JQueryMobile content jump after page transition (Using data-position="fixed")

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

I've been trying for days to get smooth transitions in a RhoMobile project i'm working on, and i've managed to fix most of the glitches in page transitions: flickers, header jumping a couple pixels on transitions, etc...

But one problem still remains: It seems that when going from one page to another, just after the transitions is done (the destination page alredy appears), it will scroll down about 15-20 px, as if during the transition, it paints the destination page content not taking into account the px needed to display the header, and then later, adds that space.

I've seen this question asked before, but with no answer. Notice its not a duplicate of all the questions regarding flickering on transitions, since if alredy managed to get that working.

My viewport is as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, height=device-height, width=device-width">
```

I've tried using javascript to set overflow: hidden while transitioning, but this has no effect on android.

Any suggestion appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: `data-position=fixed` is only used on header and footer.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I didn't make that clear, i'm using data-position="fixed" on the header. The header stays where it should, but its the page content that has the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: I think this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828783/stop-page-resize-during-transition-with-jquery-mobile however, the fixes suggested there are not usefull for me, using javascript te set overflow: hidden does nothing, and trying to set height based on pixel wont work either, since this app has to work on several different smartphones.

Comment: Strangest thing is that on the main index page (application menu), this does not happen. All the elements are in place during the transition, and don't change position after finishing the animation.

Comment: try this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` its recommended by jqm. I guess `height=device-height` is causing this.

Comment: Tried this, still happening :(. "height=device-height" was added for testing purposes, but had no effect, I should have removed it.

Comment: I got the cause of this problem: It happens because i'm using a header that also includes a "subtitle". When I remove the subtitle and use default header size, the content wont "jump" on transitions. However, I still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: post your markup, i will test it.

Comment: Omar, i've prepared a jsfiddle to explain better what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/gkv3T/

It will only happen on the first time you transition: you see how during the transition animation, the position of the content is about 15 pixels more to the top, and after half a second, gets moved down and matches the headers height. It seems like jquerymobile has a default height for fixed headers, and then realizes header is actually bigger.

In my test device (Android 4.1), this is more noticeable, and happens all the times (not just on the first transition)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you use extra height for your fixed headers and you want jquerymobile to respect that size at all times (also in transitions), you have to specify its height in css:

```
.ui-page-header-fixed{
    padding-top: 3.5em !important; 
}
```